# Setting property of Object in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
<mx:Canvas id="maincanvas" backgroundColor="7000" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:TextArea backgroundAlpha="0"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

However if I try creating a new textarea object via:

```
var textarea:TextArea = new TextArea ();
textarea.backgroundAlpha = 0;
maincanvas.addChild(textarea);
```

flex throws the error :

1119: Access of possibly undefined property backgroundAlpha through a reference with static type mx.controls:TextArea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backgroundAlpha` is a style, so you've got to set it with:

```
textarea.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", 0);
```